# Do not show specific notification React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, push-notification, expo

I do not want to show "NEW_MSG" Push Notification type in a specific screen. I coded below code but when I test it I always get a notification. How can I fix it?

```
  useEffect(() => {
    notificationListener.current = Notifications.addNotificationReceivedListener(
      (notification) => {
        const {
          room_id,
          message_text,
          type,
        } = notification.request.content.data;
      
        
        // I do not want to show NEW_MSG,
         if (type == "NEW_MSG") {
           console.log(notification);
           return;
         }

      }
    );

    return () => {
      // Unsubscribe when component unmmounts
      Notifications.removeNotificationSubscription(
        notificationListener.current
      );
    };
  }, []);
```

Note: I use Expo Notifications

Answer (score 2):

I believe what you want to do is set up a single custom notification handler that refers to a state variable that you can set/unset on your special screen using the useEffect pa ttern you demonstrated above (i.e. the componentDidMount functional useEffect style).

Apologies, I didn't try writing this up myself first so it may need syntactic help. But it would go something like this...

**Setup the handler function for your app and use it for handling your notifications**

```
// The function must refer to a state variable that reacts to whether you're on the screen
let notificationHandlerFn = (notification: Notification) => {
  {
    shouldShowAlert: !onMySuperDuperScreen,   // special state variable
    shouldPlaySound: false,
    shouldSetBadge: false,
  }};

// Register the handler to use the function
Notifications.setNotificationHandler({
  handleNotification: notificationHandlerFn
});
```

**Later, on your special screen**

```
   // Use useEffect to control the state variable
useEffect(() => {
    onMySuperDuperScreen = true;

    return () => {
      onMySuperDuperScreen = false;
    };
  }, []);
```

Take a look at the expo docs [here](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/notifications/#notification) for details. Read in the section is titled "Handling incoming notifications when the app is in foreground".

Answer (score 1):

with this class (Android) you can overwrite the expo notification service and to decide show or not an push notification.

```
import expo.modules.notifications.notifications.JSONNotificationContentBuilder;
import expo.modules.notifications.notifications.interfaces.NotificationsScoper;
import expo.modules.notifications.notifications.model.Notification;
import expo.modules.notifications.notifications.model.NotificationContent;
import expo.modules.notifications.notifications.model.NotificationRequest;
import expo.modules.notifications.notifications.model.triggers.FirebaseNotificationTrigger;
import expo.modules.notifications.notifications.service.NotificationsHelper;
import expo.modules.notifications.tokens.interfaces.FirebaseTokenListener;

public class FirebaseMessageService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

@Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
}

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    
    try {
        
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(remoteMessage.getData());
        JSONObject body = new JSONObject(json.getString("body"));
        
        if (body...) {  //HERE YOUR CONDITIONS
            
            //NOT SHOW RETURN:
            return;
            
        }else{
            
            //SHOW EXPO NOTIFICATION
            createNotificationsHelper().notificationReceived(createNotification(remoteMessage));

        }
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        
    }   
}

public void sendRegistrationToServer(String token) {
}

protected NotificationsHelper createNotificationsHelper() {
  return new NotificationsHelper(this, NotificationsScoper.create(this).createReconstructor());
}

protected Notification createNotification(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
  String identifier = remoteMessage.getMessageId();
  if (identifier == null) {
    identifier = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
  }
  JSONObject payload = new JSONObject(remoteMessage.getData());
  NotificationContent content = new JSONNotificationContentBuilder(this).setPayload(payload).build();
  NotificationRequest request = createNotificationRequest(identifier, content, new FirebaseNotificationTrigger(remoteMessage));
  return new Notification(request, new Date(remoteMessage.getSentTime()));
}

protected NotificationRequest createNotificationRequest(String identifier, NotificationContent content, FirebaseNotificationTrigger notificationTrigger) {
  return new NotificationRequest(identifier, content, notificationTrigger);
}
```

}

in your manifest:

```
<service
    android:name=".FirebaseMessageService"
    android:exported="false">
    <intent-filter android:priority="-1">
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
    </intent-filter>
  </service>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution - you can check notification data and determine if you want to show it's alert and play alert sound. Here is my code:

```js
    // https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/notifications/#handling-incoming-notifications-when-the-app-is-in-foreground
    Notifications.setNotificationHandler({
      handleNotification: async (notification) => {
        let shouldShow;

        // will not show alert and sound if we already in this chat
        const chatId = notification?.request?.content?.data?.chatId;
        const currentRouteNameIsChat = navigationRef.getCurrentRoute().name === "Chat";
        const currentRouteChatIdIsSame = navigationRef.getCurrentRoute().params?.chatId == chatId;

        if (chatId && currentRouteNameIsChat && currentRouteChatIdIsSame) {
          shouldShow = false;
        } else {
          shouldShow = true;
        }

        return {
          shouldShowAlert: shouldShow,
          shouldPlaySound: shouldShow,
          shouldSetBadge: false,
        };
      },
    });
```

`setNotificationHandler` docs: https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/notifications/#setnotificationhandlerhandler-notificationhandler--null-void